# What does "the discovery" refer to?

Tags: meaning

> The admiral begins his expedition, searching for an entrance to a
> hidden world.  The purpose is **the discovery** and the release to the
> world of the unknown treasures  of Antarctica in the interests of all
> mankind.

What does "the discovery" refer to?

Source: Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The admiral begins his expedition, searching for an entrance to a hidden world. The purpose is **the discovery** and the release to the world **of the unknown treasures** of Antarctica in the interests of all mankind.

The conjunction "and" joins "the discovery" and "the release to the world".  His purpose is two-fold: find treasures in Antarctica and then release them to the world.